# iOS UI Testing tap on first index of the table

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I just started studying for UI testing in iOS. When I press record and tap on first index of the table, it generate codes like this.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.tables.staticTexts[@"Apr 04 16:28"] tap];
```

It is good if all my data are constant. But those text will be changed from time to time. How can I modify these code so that it will always tap on the first index of the table?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`-elementBoundByIndex`](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCUIElementQuery.html#//api/name/elementBoundByIndex:) on your app's `cells`.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[[app.cells elementBoundByIndex: 0] tap];
```

Comment: Sweet. Short and hit target. Thank :)

Comment: In Swift 4, Used "app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).tap()" instead the "[[app.cells elementBoundByIndex: 0] tap];"

Answer (score 5):

**Swift**

If you're doing UI Testing, this will be helpful:

```
let cellCount = app.tables.cells.count
XCTAssertTrue(cellCount > 0)

let firstCell = app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0)
XCTAssertTrue(firstCell.exists)
firstCell.tap()
```

To answer your question though, you only need these 2 lines:

```
let firstCell = app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0)
firstCell.tap()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

[@Joe Masilotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384110/joe-masilotti)'s solution didn't work for me. So I used:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.tables["table's accessibilityIdentifier"].cells.allElementsBoundByIndex.first?.tap()
```

"table's accessibilityIdentifier" should be replaced by your table's *accessibilityIdentifier*.

Possibly this will save a few minutes for someone.